The equivalent condition for sequentially compact in $L^2$ and $L^p$
Assume that $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set and $p>2$.
Prove: $A$ is sequentially compact in $L^p(\Omega)$ if and only if
$(a):$ $A$ is sequentially compact in $L^2(\Omega)$.
$(b):$ For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $m\ge 1$ such that for any $f\in A$ $, \int_{\{x\in\Omega:|f(x)|\geqslant m\}}\left|f(x)\right|^pdx\leqslant\varepsilon^p.$
$\Rightarrow:$ If $A$ is sequentially compact in $L^p(\Omega)$, by the inequality $\|f\|_2\leq\|f\|_p\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}}$, I can get $L^p(\Omega)\in L^2(\Omega)$. Then $(a)$ is proved.
But I donot know how to prove $(b)$ and the inverse $\Leftarrow$
How should I consider this question?  I want some tips.
Thanks.

For (b) it might be better to use that a sequentially compact set is compact in the usual sense (for any epsilon it can be covered by finitely many epsilon balls).
